# How do I add Marker Clusters to my Google Map?

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I can't figure out how to add Marker Clusters to this map. It's used with Wordpress, so that the user can add locations to it from the Wordpress dashboard. I'm pretty new to Google API and I'm not having success with any examples that I find. Any help is appreciated!

```
<?php // Index template
get_header(); ?>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<div class="twelve column">
        <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

            <div class="intro">
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                <hr>
            </div>

                <?php the_content(); ?>

                <header class="clearfix"></header>
                        <div id="mapcanvas"></div>
                                <?php
                                // For creating multiple, customized loops.
                                // http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query
                                $custom_query = new WP_Query('post_type=locations'); // exclude category 9
                                while($custom_query->have_posts()) : $custom_query->the_post(); ?>
                            s       <?php if(get_field('link')): ?>
                                      <div>
                                        <?php while(has_sub_field('link')): ?>
                                          <div>
                                              <p><?php the_sub_field('url'); ?></p>
                                          </div>
                                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                                      </div>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php endwhile; ?>
                                <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // reset the query ?>

                                <?php
                                function get_single_term($post_id, $taxonomy)
                                {
                                  $terms = wp_get_object_terms($post_id, $taxonomy);
                                  if(!is_wp_error($terms)) {
                                    return '<a href="'.get_term_link($terms[0]->slug, $taxonomy).'">'.$terms[0]->name.'</a>';
                                  }
                                }

                                $i = 0;

                                // For creating multiple, customized loops.
                                // http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query
                                    $custom_query = new WP_Query('post_type=location&posts_per_page=-1');
                                    while($custom_query->have_posts()) : $custom_query->the_post();

                                      $title = get_the_title(); // Location title
                                      $map   = get_field('location'); // ACF location contains address and coordinates
                                      $terms = strip_tags( get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'distributors', '', ' & ' )); // Get distributor terms and rm links
                                      $info  = '<strong>' . $title . '</strong><br>' . $map['address']; // Info window content
                                      $link = get_field('link');
                                      if($link){
                                        $info .= '<br><a href="http://'. $link .'">'. $link .'</a>';
                                      }
                                      $location[$i][0] = $title; // Store the post title
                                      $location[$i][1] = $map['coordinates']; // Store the ACF coordinates
                                      $location[$i][2] = json_encode($info); // Store info window content
                                      $location[$i][3] = strip_tags( get_single_term( $post->ID, 'distributors' )); // Get first term for marker icon

                                      $i ++;
                                    endwhile; ?>
                                    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // reset the query ?>

                                <script>
                                  var geocoder;
                                  var map;
                                $(function initialize() {
                                  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                                  // Center map on our main location
                                  var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.583013,-93.63701500000002);
                                  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

                                  // https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling
                                  // Create an array of styles.
                                  var styles = [
                                    {
                                      stylers: [
                                        { saturation: -99.9 }
                                      ]
                                    }
                                  ];

                                  // Create a new StyledMapType object, passing it the array of styles,
                                  // as well as the name to be displayed on the map type control.
                                  var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles, {name: 'exile'});

                                  // Create a map object, and include the MapTypeId to add
                                  // to the map type control.
                                  var mapOptions = {
                                    mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
                                    center: myLatLng,
                                    zoom: 14,
                                    disableDefaultUI: false,
                                    scrollwheel: true,
                                    draggable: true
                                  };
                                  // Display a map on the page
                                  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcanvas"), mapOptions);
                                  map.setTilt(45);

                                  //Associate the styled map with the MapTypeId and set it to display.
                                  map.mapTypes.set('exile', styledMap);
                                  map.setMapTypeId('exile');

                                // Marker icons
                                  typeObject = {
                                    "Others" : {
                                      "icon" : new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://exilebrewing.com/site/img/beer-mug.png', new google.maps.Size(18,26), new google.maps.Point(0,0), new google.maps.Point(9,26)),
                                      "shadow" : new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/shadow50.png', new google.maps.Size(40,34))
                                    }
                                  }

                                  // http://wrightshq.com/playground/placing-multiple-markers-on-a-google-map-using-api-3/
                                  // Multiple Markers
                                  var markers = [
                                    ["Exile Brewing Co", 41.583013,-93.63701500000002,"Others"],
                                    <?php
                                    if (count($location)>0) {
                                      foreach ($location as $key => $value){
                                        if ($key < (count($location)-1)){
                                          echo '["' . $location[$key][0] . '",' . $location[$key][1] . ',"' . $location[$key][3] . '"], ' . "\n";
                                        } else {
                                          echo '["' . $location[$key][0] . '",' . $location[$key][1] . ',"' . $location[$key][3] . '"]';
                                        }
                                      }
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                  ];

                                  // Info Window Content
                                  var infoWindowContent = [
                                    ["<strong>Exile Brewing Co.</strong><br>1514 Walnut Street, Des Moines"],
                                    <?php
                                    if (count($location)>0) {
                                      foreach ($location as $key => $value){
                                        if ($key < (count($location)-1)) {
                                          echo '[' . $location[$key][2] . '], ' . "\n";
                                        } else {
                                          echo '[' . $location[$key][2] . ']';
                                        }
                                      }
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                  ];

                                  // Display multiple markers on a map
                                  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;

                                  // Loop through our array of markers & place each one on the map
                                  for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
                                    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]); // ACF coordinates
                                    var icon = typeObject[markers[i][3]]['icon'];
                                    var shadow = typeObject[markers[i][3]]['shadow'];
                                    bounds.extend(position);
                                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                      position: position,
                                      map: map,
                                      title: markers[i][0],
                                      icon: icon,
                                      shadow: shadow
                                    });

                                    // Allow each marker to have an info window
                                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                                      return function() {
                                        infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
                                        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                                      }
                                    })(marker, i));

                                    // Automatically center the map fitting all markers on the screen
                                    //map.fitBounds(bounds);
                                  }
                                  function codeAddress() {
                                  var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
                                  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
                                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                                      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                                      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                          map: map,
                                          position: results[0].geometry.location
                                      });
                                    } else {
                                      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
                                    }
                                  });
                                }
                                  // Override our map zoom level once our fitBounds function runs (Make sure it only runs once)
                                  var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
                                    this.setZoom(15);
                                    google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
                                  });

                                });
                                </script>
                                  <div id="panel">
                                    <input id="address" type="textbox" value="Sydney, NSW">
                                    <input type="button" value="Geocode" onclick="codeAddress()">
                                  </div>
                                <div id="map-canvas"></div>


                <footer class="clearfix"></footer>
    <?php endwhile;?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Some

Answer (score 0):

There can be three kind of clustering of markers as follows

**Grid-Based Clustering**
Grid-based clustering is probably the most common approach for clustering markers. It will divide the map into a grid and group all markers within each square into a cluster. Although an efficient technique, it has some obvious limitations since it can lead to unwanted results. Two markers that are really close together but in separate squares will, for example, not be grouped into the same cluster.

**Distance-Based Clustering**
This technique looks at each individual marker and checks whether it’s nearby other markers. If it’s close enough to another marker, the two of them will be grouped into a cluster.
Distance-based clustering also has its drawbacks. Since the clusters will appear at random
locations depending on where a cluster is formed they may not make sense for the user.

**Regional Clustering**
A third technique is regional clustering. What this means is that you define different geographical regions, such as counties or states. All markers in each region will be grouped into a cluster. You also define at which zoom level the cluster will break up into separate markers (or smaller clusters). The advantage of this technique is that you can create clusters that make more sense to the user. The drawback is that it requires more effort and can’t as easily be automated as the other clustering techniques.

**Example**
Shows the complete code. When you run this page, it will add 100 markers at random
locations at the visible part of the map. If you want to try adding a different number of markers, just change the number in the for loop.

```
(function() {
window.onload = function(){
// Creating a map
var options = {
zoom: 3,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.09, -95.71),
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
// Getting the boundaries of the map
var bounds = map.getBounds();
// Getting the corners of the map
var southWest = bounds.getSouthWest();
var northEast = bounds.getNorthEast();
// Calculating the distance from the top to the bottom of the map
var latSpan = northEast.lat() - southWest.lat();
// Calculating the distance from side to side
var lngSpan = northEast.lng() - southWest.lng();
// Creating a loop
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
// Creating a random position
var lat = southWest.lat() + latSpan * Math.random();
var lng = southWest.lng() + lngSpan * Math.random();
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
// Adding a marker to the map
new google.maps.Marker({
position: latlng,
map: map
});
}
});
};
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(13.696516,-89.208765);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 17,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
  var contentString = '<h1>Aditivos de El salvador</h1><p>33 Av. Sur #661, Colonia Flor Blanca, San Salvador El Salvador.</p>';

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
    });
  var image = '<?php echo bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/iconmapa.png';
  var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      icon: image
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(beachMarker, 'click', function() {
  infowindow.open(map,beachMarker);
  });
}
</script>
```